# How to access parameters from another controller without redirecting? Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-thymeleaf

Controllers:

```
    @GetMapping("/reservations/chooseExpert")
    public String chooseExpert( Model model, @RequestParam("gameId") Long gameId) {
        String gameName = gameService.getGameById(gameId).getName();
        List<Coach> experts = coachService.getAllCoachesByGameId(gameId);

        model.addAttribute("gameId", gameId);
        model.addAttribute("experts", experts);
        model.addAttribute("gameName", gameName);

        return "experts.html";
    }

    @GetMapping("/reservations/form")
    public String showForm(Model model, @RequestParam("coachId") Long coachId) {
        Coach coach = coachService.getCoachNameById(coachId);
        model.addAttribute("coach", coach);
        return "form.html";
    }
```

I need to get **gameId** in second controller, are there any ways?

Redirecting will definitely not help in this case. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not simply retrieve the gameId as param of second method?

Comment: request param? I got error.

Comment: @ttt you can add gameId in the RequestParam like you have done it for coachId

Comment: @SachinMewar tried and got error that gameId is missing.

Comment: Have you added @RequestParam gameId in your controller method?

Comment: Did you try it like this? `public String showForm(Model model, @RequestParam("coachId") Long coachId, @RequestParam(gameId) Long gameId)`

Comment: @meridbt, yes, exactly, got an error as mentioned that this's not present. Even though I keep gameId in the experts.html.

Comment: Show the code how you call `showForm` method

Comment: @meridbt, sorry , already solve it. Changed to PostMapping.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achive it.

1. As mentioned in the comments you can pass the "gameId" parameter as a @RequestParam in showForm:

```
@GetMapping("/reservations/form")
    public String showForm(Model model, @RequestParam("gameId") Long gameId, @RequestParam("coachId") Long coachId) {
```

2. You could also put "gameId" in session, making it available in the second method:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("gameId")
public class SomeController {

  @GetMapping("/reservations/chooseExpert")
  public String chooseExpert(Model model, @RequestParam("gameId") Long gameId) {
    String gameName = gameService.getGameById(gameId).getName();
    List<Coach> experts = coachService.getAllCoachesByGameId(gameId);

    model.addAttribute("gameId", gameId);
    model.addAttribute("experts", experts);
    model.addAttribute("gameName", gameName);

    return "experts.html";
  }

  @GetMapping("/reservations/form")
  public String showForm(Model model, @RequestParam("coachId") Long coachId, @ModelAttribute("gameId") String gameId) {
    ...
  }

}
```